# I'm writing a NewDate class and using it in a TestNewDate class. I think there is an issue with my validdate method

Tags: java

I'm writing a `NewDate` class containing several methods that I am executing in a `TestNewDate` class.

When all the information is inputted correctly, I get the expected outcome, however when I intentionally put in information such as the incorrect date format or leaving a digit out of the year, my expected outcome should be "invalid date", but I get a `java.time.DateTimeException` instead.

There must be some kind of issue with my valid date method.

```
public boolean validDate (int day, int month, int year) {
     boolean validdate = true;

     if((month >= 1 && month <= 12) && (day >= 1 && day <= 31))
     {
         validdate = true;

            //For months with 30 days
            if((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day <= 30)) {
               validdate = true;
            }

            //For months with 31 days
            if((month == 1 || month == 2 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31)){
               validdate = true;
            }

            if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
                validdate = false;
            }
            if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
                validdate = false;
            }

            if (month == 2) {
                if (leapYear(year)) {
                    validdate = true;
                    return (day <= 29);
                } else {
                    validdate = true;
                    return (day <= 28)
                }
            }  
        }
    return validdate;
  }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing that exception?  What are the values on that line when the exception happens?

Comment: Are you saying February has 31 days?

Comment: Take the very first condition. If the month is negative then the outermost if-statement will fail. `validdate` was initialised to true, so the result of the method is true.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it for you and commented the changes. It wasn't too far wrong, but there were a lot of redundant checks.

```
public boolean validDate (int day, int month, int year) {
    //boolean validdate = true; don't store a variable, just return early

    if((month >= 1 && month <= 12) && (day >= 1 && day <= 31))
    {
        //For months with 30 days
        if((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day > 30)) // reversed day condition
        {
            return false; // reversed
        }

        /*
        No need to check this, day is already asserted to be: day >= 1 && day <= 31
        if((month == 1 || month == 2 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31))
        {
            validdate = true;
        }*/

        /* We already did these checks at the top: (month >= 1 && month <= 12)

        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            validdate = false;
        }
        if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
            validdate = false;
        }*/

        if (month == 2) {
            if (leapYear(year))
            {
                //validdate = true; 
                return (day <= 29);
            }
            else
            {
                // validdate = true;
                return (day <= 28);
            }
        }
        return true; // added
    }
    return false; // changed from validdate
}
```